# How to set webhook for telegram bot in python?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, bots, telegram

I've created a bot and it works fine with heroku. I wanted to use webhooks to handle messages but i can't understand how to do it. Here's what i did:

1. Uploaded this code to heroku

telegrampiu24.py

```
import telepot
import json
from flask import Flask, request, abort
from telepot.namedtuple import *
bot = telepot.Bot("123456789:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("post")
        return Response('post',status=200)
    else:
        print("get")
        return Response('get',status=200)

if __name__ == '__main__' or __name__ == '__telegrampiu24__':
    app.run()
```

2. Set the webhook with *https://api.telegram.org/bot123456789:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/setwebhook?url=https://provaxyz1.herokuapp.com/* (obviously with my correct token)

I'm stuck here since if i send a message to my bot and see the logs on heroku i always get errors

```
2021-02-26T13:12:24.889213+00:00 app[test.1]:  * Serving Flask app "telegrampiu24" (lazy loading)
2021-02-26T13:12:24.889246+00:00 app[test.1]:  * Environment: production
2021-02-26T13:12:24.889247+00:00 app[test.1]:    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
2021-02-26T13:12:24.889247+00:00 app[test.1]:    Use a production WSGI server instead.
2021-02-26T13:12:24.889290+00:00 app[test.1]:  * Debug mode: off
2021-02-26T13:12:24.891889+00:00 app[test.1]:  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2021-02-26T13:12:26.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-02-26T13:13:02.086234+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=POST path="/" host=provaxyz1.herokuapp.com request_id=54bdbd45bdf fwd="IP" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong, any help is very appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the `Procfile` look like?

Comment: test: python "telegrampiu24.py"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, the document on [The Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-naming-and-location):

> A Heroku app’s `web` process type is special: it’s the only process type that can receive external HTTP traffic from Heroku’s routers. If your app includes a web server, you should declare it as your app’s `web` process.

With this in mind, your error: `No web processes running` suggests you should change your `Procfile` to contain:

```
web: python "telegrampiu24.py"
```

This issue woudln't have happened before, as prior to putting webhook support in your bot, it didn't need to receive HTTP traffic because the other method uses 'polling' where the process connects to telegram's servers as a client.

Although be aware that this is still Flask's dev server.  You should look to deploy with a production WSGI server like `gunicorn` in the long run.  Add `gunicorn` to your `requirements.txt` and then have the Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn telegrampiu24:app
```

Comment: Really thanks for the answer, it was so helpful! Even if some things aren't completely clear to me now it works!